# How to easily build chords on fl studio

Tags: electronic-music

I'm kinda like a Newby to fl studio. And I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Basically I need to know how to build a melody line, for any song. And I realised I need to learn how to create chords.

Someone said something about the I, ii, IV, V chords and I really still don't understand it, so i wouldn't mind if I can get a picture description on how I can quickly familiarise myself with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"Someone said something about the I, ii, IV, V chords and I really still don't understand it, so i wouldn't mind if I can get a picture description on how I can quickly familiarise myself with it."

Hi.. I want to help you to answer your above question :

I used to fl studio long time ago, now I works on Nuendo. The simplest way for me to create chords in fl studio is just by plug my midi-controller devices and records those chords.

yap, the I, ii, IV, V chords is a abbreviate of a chords so we can call any long terms chords, like D minor we can call it ii chords.

Basically we have I to VII chords. 
I want to example usability in "C based Notes."

- I stands for C
- ii for Dm, II for D
- iii for Em, III for E
- IV for F
- V for G
- VI for A, vi for Am
- VII for B

so if someone ask you to play these I,IV,V,ii chords, you'll play chords C ...... F .... G ... Dm ... with your "improvisations plays"

thats all

Regards
(corrected, thanks to Dom)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do it easily. For the you have to choose good instrument and then go to piano roll of the plugin. After that go to menu >> chords >> and then select the chord you want. I wish you!!

[image: Like this]